# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@4ce4fde9" when trying to clone the subclass of an abstract class using a copy const

Tags: java, reflection, clone, classcastexception, illegalargumentexception

Here is the complete cloning process:

```
void ghost(){
//accesses player hotbar to grab the in-hand object
int hotbarAccessIndex = game.keyManager.lastNumKey;

//variable toClone is the object grabbed from the hotbar
AbstractSprite toClone = game.player.hotbar.inventoryArray[hotbarAccessIndex];

//Class of toClone is grabbed 
Class toClass = toClone.getClass();

//toClass is used to grab toClone's copy constructor
Constructor toConstruct = null;
try{
  toConstruct = toClass.getDeclaredConstructor(P4Torio.class, toClass);
} catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
  print(e);
}

AbstractSprite clone = null;
try{
  //AbstractSprite[] params = {toClone};
  clone = (AbstractSprite) toConstruct.newInstance(P4Torio.class, toClone);
} catch(Exception e){
  print(e + "\n");
}
```

I get the exception listed in the title when attempting to do the following:

```
AbstractSprite clone = null;
try{
  //AbstractSprite[] params = {toClone};
  clone = (AbstractSprite) toConstruct.newInstance(P4Torio.class, toClone);
} catch(Exception e){
  print(e + "\n");
}
```

Here is the copy constructor of toClone:

```
API(API other){
super(other.x, other.y, other.size, other.direction, other.path, other.tint);
```

}

Here is the copy constructor of AbstractSprite:

```
AbstractSprite(AbstractSprite other){
this.x = other.x; this.y = other.y; 
this.w = other.w; this.h = other.h; 
this.size = other.size;
this.direction = other.direction; this.path = other.path;
this.sprite = other.sprite;
this.col = other.col; this.tint = other.tint;
```

}

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@8647ad5
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at P4Torio$PlaneManager.ghost(P4Torio.java:318)
    at P4Torio$Game.play(P4Torio.java:217)
    at P4Torio.draw(P4Torio.java:31)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2201)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$10.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1422)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:354)
```

and the error occurs on this line:

```
clone = (AbstractSprite) toConstruct.newInstance(P4Torio.class, toClone);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You calling `getDeclaredConstructor(P4Torio.class, toClass)` with two parameters. What does that look like? You're also calling a constructor with two parameters in `newInstance(P4Torio.class, toClone)`. You've only included constructors that take one parameter. It would also be helpful if you were to identify which line gives you the error and include the stack trace. Not just the error.

Comment: I'm using two arguments because the constructor actually requires two arguments. I came to this conclusion after printing the constructor and getting this: `P4Torio$API(P4Torio,P4Torio$API)`. Also, when I print the parameters I get this: `[Ljava.lang.reflect.Parameter;@d0518fe`. That might be useful. I don't really know why two arguments are required, but I'm assuming it has something to do with reflection. I'd love an explanation. Anyways, there you go @Scratte

Comment: What happens if you don't cast it? Does it initialize?

Comment: So apparently you forgot to mention that this is an inner class. But when the parameter type is `P4Torio` you can not pass `P4Torio.class` as actual argument, as that is an instance of `Class`. You must provide an instance of `P4Torio`.

Comment: @Scratte It doesn’t initialize because it apparently returns a member of the object class

Comment: @Holger I feel like kind of a dunce rn. That makes a lot of sense, and I’ll try it out as soon as I have the chance